# na.locf using group_by for 177 groups

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

I am merging two data frames however some data points are missing and I, therefore, want the merged data frame to use the last known value to overwrite the missing values.

Currently, my code is as follows:

```
CombData$`Price Close` <- CombData %>%
group_by(ISIN) %>%
mutate(na.locf(CombData$`Price Close`, na.rm = TRUE))
```

However, when looking at the output I can see that no missing values get replaced. Below is an example of how the data currently looks:

```
    ISIN            Date        Price Close
20  BSP951331318    2010-01-29  434.0
21  BSP951331318    2010-01-31  NA
```

Here I would like row 21 to have a closing price of 434.

Comment: Use `CombData %>%
  group_by(ISIN) %>%
  mutate(\`Price Close\` = na.locf(\`Price Close\`, na.rm = TRUE))
` Or `CombData %>%
  group_by(ISIN) %>%
  fill(\`Price Close\`)`

Comment: When using the first code i get the following error message:
Error: Column `Price Close` must be length 1037 (the group size) or one, not 960

Comment: Use `na.locf0` like this: `CombData %>% group_by(ISIN) %>% mutate(\`Price Close\` = na.locf0(\`Price Close\`) ) %>% ungroup`

Answer (score 0):

just `na.locf(CombData)` should be fine for this.